# Is it possible to work on single branch with pessimistic approach?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

My team and me are going to work using [Trunk Based Development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) approach. Is it possible in VSTS (or broader, in Git) to have only master branch and after each `push` (and before `merge`) to have validation - test are run. Image as an example:

[image]

No one is working on branches, except rare situations. Team tends to commit small pieces of code directly to master.

**Is it possible to achieve?**

Comment: What do you mean by "possible to achieve"? practical? or litterally "possible"? Because of course it's possible.

Comment: Literally possible. We wonder if TFS (git) allows to do that thing without creating custom hooks and hacks.

Comment: Due To how git works and how pull requests are implemented you need to create temporary topic branches in all workflow that verify the commit prior to updating master. With some scripts in CI or split pull/push remotes you can achieve similar work flows without creating topic branches. These aren't hacks, they're how git works. But you lose the advantages of pull request reviews. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pull Requests for this, set a validation build and set it to auto-commit on success. It does require a server-side topic branch, as the Build system can't merge from your local repository.

You'd be required to do your work locally, push it to a temporary topic branch, let the pull request validation build run and let it auto-commit & delete branch on success.

### Alternative

There is no "post receive hook" on the server to process new commits, but what you can do is a little more work to setup:

- Add a second repository and push the same contents there.
- Configure clients to split their push and pull remotes. Pull from the Master repository, push to the newly created repository.
- Create a build on the new repository to validate newly pushed commits.
- Add a conditional task to the end of the build that pushes the contents to the master repository.
- Add a conditional task to the end of the build that reverts the repository to last known good if the build fails.

This way people can only pull from the latest "succeeded" repo.

### Alternative 2

You may also want to look into Explorer, Expand, Extract, (Test && Commit) || Revert and Limbo! as branching models to look into. These patterns are emerging from Uber and Facebook where they work with too many people on a single branch to make pull requests usable.

They strive for a very strong TDD style development where code is only committed if tests are passing and code is pushed early and often.

See also:

- https://sourcediving.com/kent-beck-explore-expand-extract-tcr-and-limbo-b007b397c12e
- https://medium.com/@kentbeck_7670/test-commit-revert-870bbd756864

Comment: This is what we practice nowadays. We consider this approach as harming, because of creating branches. People tend to defer "merge-to-master" moment to later because it takes time.

Comment: There is no 'tentative push' option in Azure DevOps directly. But you may be able to get this to work let me update the answer.

Comment: @Fka What is "harming" about creating branches? Branches are a core Git concept and using them liberally is **encouraged**.

Comment: Creating branches isn't harming. Leaving code on "dead-branches" is harming. Harming is also waiting till the end of a feature you're working on. If everyone works on master, people can give you feedback right away when you finish your piece of code (commit changes), not wait until everyone finish feature and feature branch is merged to master. We don't condemn branches - we just want to reduce some "harming" situations.

Comment: It sounds like you have a people problem and not a tech problem. You could simply fail and require review on pull requests that have commits older than X days. Unless people force rewrite the history on the branch, that will prevent people from pushing old code.